# Round Border With Background Image Button swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm using this code to create round Border Button With Background Image

```
{  
  Button.layer.cornerRadius = clear.frame.width/2 
  Button.clipsToBounds = true
  Button.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
  Button.layer.borderColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 91/256, green: 87/256, blue: 115/256, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
}
```

And this is the outcome:

[image]

I want create a margin between the Button and the rounded border to this outcome:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks everyone for editing my question ,i am beginner so i extremely sorry for mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting background image you can set it as image to UIButton.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
yourButton.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```

Using Storyboard, from attribute inspector.

[image]

You can also set content, title and image insets (*top, left, bottom and right*) from size inspector.

- Set **Content Insets** to set image and title both at a time.
- Set **Title Insets** to set title at a time.
- Set **Image Insets** to set image at a time.

  [image]